# tablelayoutpanel cell not evenly padded in c# win forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have a tablelayoutpanel.And during run-time i am generating some labels dynamically, each having a purple round image.Now some images/labels are evenly padded inside each tablelayoutpanel cell but some are not.Please see the image..
[image]

Labels on the top 2 rows are evenly padded while rows starting form 3rd have shrunk. Why is this happening? What need to be done to get rid of this problem?Thanks in advance.

Comment: tablelayoutpanel dock property is fill.

Comment: You should set the properties of `tablelayoutpanel cell`

Comment: Show code which generate new `Label` and add them to `TableLayoutPanel`

Comment: You should set `ColumnStyles` and `RowStyles` to suitable values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set [`ColumnStyles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.columnstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`RowStyles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.rowstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) to suitable values.

For example for each column and row, you can define the style using [`SizeType.Percent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayb59253(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`SizeType.Absolute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayb59253(v=vs.110).aspx) and set an equal value for them.

In the below example:

- I set `AutoSize` property of `TableLayoutPanel` to true
- Set `AutoScroll` property of `Form` to true
- Set column styles to `SizeType.Percent` using equal percent (`100/columnCount`)
- Set row styles to `SizeType.Absolute` using equal vaules `30`
- Add controls dynamically.

**Sample Code:**

```
int columnCount = 4;
int rowCount = 13;

this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = columnCount;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = rowCount;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear();
this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();
this.tableLayoutPanel1.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.BackColor = Color.White;
this.tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = true;

for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
{
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(
        new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100 / columnCount));
}
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(
        new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 30));
}

this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
{
    var label = new Label();
    label.Text = i.ToString();
    label.Font = new Font(label.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    label.AutoSize = false;
    label.Size = new Size(30, 30);
    label.Image = Properties.Resources.Circle;
    label.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label);
}
this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Reza or anyone else out there how do i reduce the overall width of the tablelayoutpanel still keeping its autosize to true???And also please remember that the above tablelayoutpanel is inside the cell of another tablelayoutpanel .

Comment: The first thing that reduces space is using `label.Margin = new Padding(0);` and then if you want, you can use smaller width for labels.

Comment: i don't want to touch the width of labels rather looking for reducing the width of overall tablelayoutpanel .is that possible?

Comment: The autosize width of the panel is dependent to `Width` of label and `Margin` of label. and after you set those values to minimum acceptable values, the your panel width is in its acceptable minimum.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99060/discussion-between-gomesh-munda-and-reza-aghaei).

Comment: Another (not so good approach) is using an auto-scroll (but not auto-size) table layout panel. it can have smaller width but with an ugly horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Well reza i have solved the issue of unnecessary h-scroll bar appearance by setting padding-right=20 of the layout panel :)

Comment: @gomeshmunda Good job! :)